# Ask user for facebook login permissions after user has denied some permission

Tags: angular, typescript, facebook-graph-api, permissions

i am developing application on angular 4 that uses facebook login.

This app used fb photos, email, birthday etc. of the user. 
I used ngx-facebook plugin to login with facebook.

> The problem is when user logins for the first time the permission page
>   is shown and when user denies some permissions then alert message is
>   shown. after then when users again click login then facebook doesnot
>   shows the permission page.

how can i trigger the fb login permission page.

```
import { FacebookService, InitParams, LoginResponse, LoginOptions } from 'ngx-facebook';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private fb: FacebookService){}

   fbLogin() {

   const loginOptions: LoginOptions = {
        enable_profile_selector: true,
        return_scopes: true,
        scope: 'user_birthday,user_photos,email,public_profile'
      }
   this.fb.login(loginOptions).then((response) => {
      let array = response.authResponse.grantedScopes.split(',');
      if(array.length == 4){

      }else{
         this.ajaxService.alertError('You need to provide all the facebook permissions to use the app.');
      }
   });

  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be great you can format the content.

Comment: Once an app has detected that someone has denied some or all permissions, it may pass them back through the login flow once and request any required permissions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If someone has declined a permission for your app, the login dialog
>   won't let your app re-request the permission unless you pass
>   `auth_type=rerequest` along with your request.
>  See [requesting-and-revoking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking)

Try this

```
 const loginOptions: LoginOptions = {
    enable_profile_selector: true,
    return_scopes: true,
    scope: 'user_birthday,user_photos,email,public_profile'
    auth_type: 'rerequest'
  }
```

Comment: where should i add thi auth_type

Comment: @AnilShrestha most likely in your `loginOptions` ... (assuming your framework passes those parameters on into the login dialog URL 1:1 …)